# Make Xcode run current Python file in project

Tags: python, xcode

I am trying to make Xcode (v10.3) run Python scripts. I have had some success so far, by following the steps laid out in this tutorial: https://medium.com/sourleangchhean/using-xcode-to-execute-pythons-code-98be65c1ea8a

In it, Step 7 tells you that you need to add Launch arguments.

[image: LaunchArgumentsExample]

This does work, but the issue I find is that I seemingly need to do it for every python file I create. Is there a way to tell Xcode to run whatever file I have selected or to run all python scripts in a project space? Or do you need to add a new file to this Launch Arguments step every single time?

Comment: Have you tried adding executable right to the script, and having correct shellbang at the first line of it?

Comment: I have not. I'll give it a shot.